# unable to show two observable array by one ngFor : showing same values

Tags: angular

I have two Observable array. They have the same number of rows and columns every time. Now I want to show them by a single ngFor for loop.

```
scoreCardViewProfile$: Observable<ScoreCardView[]>;
scoreCardViewBuffer$: Observable<ScoreCardView[]>;
```

These two array will be filled by http response.

```
  <div *ngFor="let viewProfile of scoreCardViewProfile$ | async; let viewBuffer of scoreCardViewBuffer$ | async; let i = index">
                <div class="row">
                    <p class="pl-5 font-weight-boldest font-size-lg"> 
                    {{viewProfile.scoreCardCategoryName}}</p>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div *ngFor=" let detailsProfile of viewProfile.listOfQuestionDto; let detailsBuffer of viewBuffer.listOfQuestionDto; let j=index "
                                 class="col-6">
                                <div class="row pt-5 pb-5">
                                    <div class="col-12 text-muted font-weight-bolder">
                                        <p align="left">{{detailsProfile.question}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row pl-4">
                                        <div class="col-12 font-weight-bolder">
                                            <p>profile:{{detailsProfile.configItemName}}</p>
                                            <p>buffer: {{detailsBuffer.configItemName}}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row pl-4" *ngIf="i === viewProfile.length -1">
                    <div class="col-12 pl-0 text-muted font-weight-bolder border-bottom">
                        <p>Status</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 pl-0 font-weight-bolder">
                        <p class="pt-4">{{viewProfile.status}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

As per my understanding the below two line should show different values but they are showing same values.

```
<p>profile : {{detailsProfile.configItemName}}</p>
<p>profile : {{detailsBuffer.configItemName}}</p>
```

[I am following this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-in-two-arrays)

Comment: The provided example uses the index to access the elements of the other array. You can't use two arrays on the same directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the lengths are the same, you can just use one for the `ngFor` loop and use the index to traverse the other as well.

Here's the solution:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="scoreCardViewProfile$ | async as scoreCardViewProfile">
  <ng-container *ngIf="scoreCardViewBuffer$ | async as scoreCardViewBuffer">
    <div
      *ngFor="let viewProfile of scoreCardViewProfile; let i = index"
    >
      <div class="row">
        <p class="pl-5 font-weight-boldest font-size-lg">
          {{viewProfile.scoreCardCategoryName}}
        </p>
        <div class="col-12">
          <mat-divider></mat-divider>
          <div class="row">
            <div
              *ngFor="let detailsProfile of viewProfile.listOfQuestionDto; let j = index"
              class="col-6"
            >
              <div class="row pt-5 pb-5">
                <div class="col-12 text-muted font-weight-bolder">
                  <p align="left">{{detailsProfile.question}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row pl-4">
                  <div class="col-12 font-weight-bolder">
                    <p>profile:{{detailsProfile.configItemName}}</p>
                    <p>buffer: {{scoreCardViewBuffer[i]?.listOfQuestionDto[j]?.configItemName}}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row pl-4" *ngIf="i === viewProfile.length -1">
        <div class="col-12 pl-0 text-muted font-weight-bolder border-bottom">
          <p>Status</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 pl-0 font-weight-bolder">
          <p class="pt-4">{{viewProfile.status}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Highlights:

1. Start by resolving the observables on an `ng-container` element with `ngIf`
2. Remove double `ngFor`s; it doesn't exist.
3. Replace `detailsBuffer` with `scoreCardViewBuffer[i]?.listOfQuestionDto[j]`